# error_handling="inline" not working in exp:resso store

Tags: expresso-store, error

I have to switch off error handling and use the less than ideal EE native error handling page. I get the following error message when I try to use error_handling="inline"

Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Core::generate_page() in …./store/mod.store.php on line 784

EE version: 2.1.3 Build 20101220
Store version: 1.6.3

I'm using the example template, which comes with Exp:resso Store. All other aspects of the Store module work perfectly, it's just the error_handling which doesn't.

Thanks for any assistance/advice!

Comment: We need more information to help. What version of EE & Store are you using. What does your template look like?

Answer (score 2):

Store doesn't support ExpressionEngine 2.1.3.

You will need to upgrade to at least ExpressionEngine 2.2.0 - though preferably the most recent version. It's a good idea to keep software on an e-commerce website (where security is critical) up to date.

Comment: Thanks Adrian for the reply. I will upgrade as you suggest, however, I'm a bit surprised that "Store doesn't support ExpressionEngine 2.1.3"  as all other aspects of the Store module work perfectly on my site

Comment: I've just upgraded to 2.5.5 and all (including error_handling) works a treat. Thanks again Adrian!

Comment: No problem! For future reference, that `EE_Core::generate_page()` method was introduced in 2.2.0, hence why you were seeing the error.